# Css3 / webkit: how do I change the size of the scroll bar slider?

Tags: css, webkit

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVJGD/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgb(41,41,41);
    border-radius: 10px;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius:10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgb(111,111,111);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0,0,0);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(200,200,200), rgb(150,150,150));
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    height: 30px;
}
```

I've tried to set the height via track-piece and thumb, but I don't think that's the correct way.

Anyone know the secret? I didn't find anything on google this specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `height` and `width` properties: http://jsfiddle.net/vVJGD/8/, Webkit will assign them to the appropriate orientation.

Comment: I just tested this in chrome 17.0.963.46 and safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7) ... and I didn't see any change. maybe my webkit is broken. can you past a screen shot of the slider with say, 10px height?

Comment: Oh, you meant set the *height* of the slider? That's not possible. You'll have to make your own slider out of a `<div />` and use jQuery or something to make it function like a real scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news ;) If you're interested in making one, this is a great library to use: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: yeah, I looked at that. It's a tad messy though, so I think I'll just wait until browsers allow more customization as the scrollbar style isn't THAT important =D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. We can edit in the css the style:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px; 
  height: 50px; }
```